# node.js/Jade - How to pre-compile jade files and cache it?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Framework: node.js / express.js / Jade

Question: in production env, when a jade file is rendered by express, jade cache's it so future renders are faster.

When I start node.js app, how can I pre-compile (or) pre-render (like warmup) all the jade files so its already in cache when requests start to come in...

I can use a folder recursion, I just need to know how to pre-compile (or) pre-render.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jade has template pre-compiling and caching built in.

http://jade-lang.com/api/

Simply specify `cache: true` option to `jade.compileFile`, and iterate through all of your template files.

```
var options = {cache: true};

// iterate/recurse over your jade template files and compile them
jade.compileFile('./templates/foo.jade', options);


// Jade will load the compiled templates from cache (the file path is the key)
jade.renderFile('./templates/foo.jade');
```

Comment: Wherever you like... you could call `jade.renderFile` directly from an express route, but I suspect if you were using jade as a view engine in express it would take advantage of the built in caching.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using any parameters, you can compile jade templates directly to HTML with grunt or gulp and make it watch for file modifications

Try it from the command-line:
`jade view/map-beacons.jade -D`

If you do need to use parameters I would use something like in Andrew Lavers answer.

`compileFile` returns a function which you can use to pass in parameters i.e. `fn({ myJsVar: 'someValue' })`

There is also a client option in the command-line but I didn't find any use for it :
`jade view/map-beacons.jade -cD`

Answer (score 0):

i do this solution, this code outside http.createServer function

```
let cache_index=jade.renderFile('index.jade');
```

and when return view

```
res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');    
res.end(cache_index);
```

when use this solution server return index to 1ms
but without solution server return index between 150ms to 400ms

result:

Picture 1 with cache
[image]

Picture 2 without cache
[image]